# Display data from database inside divs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can show the data using a `MsgBox`, however I want it to place it inside divs.

Can someone explain to me how I can do this?

Code:

```
Dim connetionString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim i As Integer
connetionString = "Data Source=Gadasini-aldigim\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=allgiz;Trusted_Connection=True"
connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

connection.Open()
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gadalar", connection)
adapter.Fill(ds)
connection.Close()
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
Next
```

Comment: Why divs? If you want to display tabular data you should use a databound webcontrol like `GridView`, `ListView`, `Repeater`, `DataList` or a simple control like `ListBox` or `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add div in your .aspx file and set `runat="server"`. Now you can access it from code-behind. Then use `InnerHTML` property of div to update the content.

**Note:** As @Tim said in comment, I strongly recommend you to use data view controls to show the dataset.

ASPX:

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"></div>
```

VB.NET:

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String
    connetionString = "Data Source=Gadasini-aldigim\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=allgiz;Trusted_Connection=True"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    connection.Open()
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gadalar", connection)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    connection.Close()
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
       str= str & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) & "<br />"
    Next
    div1.InnerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add one `PlaceHolder` in the design view like:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

And add this code behind:

```
Dim connetionString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim i As Integer
connetionString = "Data Source=Gadasini-aldigim\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=allgiz;Trusted_Connection=True"
connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

connection.Open()
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gadalar", connection)
adapter.Fill(ds)
connection.Close()
Dim html As New StringBuilder()
html.Append("<div>")
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

    html.Append(+ ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1) +)

Next
html.Append("</div>")
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {.Text = html.ToString()})
```